# Problem when getting source code from .apk file?

Tags: java, android, decompiler

As per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file). I can go first two steps but, i can't get souce code using this [Java Decompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file). If anyone having good dj java decompiler then send it to me. And, also i need some good `apktool v1.x AND apktool` for getting xml files. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: see [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should use two method for getting source code from .apk files? And, download apktool and jdgui application to do below steps :

```
 * `apktool d filename.apk` it'll get the res and manifest file.

 * `dex2jar filename.apk` it'll get the source code of that apk file. 

 * Then, you should use jdgui for saving the source code.
```

Please follow these steps to get the source code. Hope this will helpful.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**
The link I provided before is dead now. I am providing a new link where you can decompile source code online. You just need to upload the apk.

[reverse engineer online](http://www.javadecompilers.com/)

**Old Answer**
this site might be helpful for you [reverse engineering](http://thomascannon.net/projects/android-reversing/)

Comment: I'm using Windows7. But, it works in Linux. Could you please give me for windows7

Comment: link dead, please fix

Comment: @FredrickGauss please check the new link

Comment: yes, this is the link which is popular in these days.

Answer (score 1):

The most you'll be able to get are image resource files and xml files, using java vm decompilation you'll be able to get byte code which you can read and tinker with a little bit, it is tough to get the actual source code for the apk unless you're the developer. To get byte code simply use smali/baksmali to assemble and disassemble bytecode. See link below:

http://code.google.com/p/smali/